# How to append byte to byte array in golang? Not byte array to byte array slices etc

Tags: go

```
var a byte
var b []byte
i know how to do this
c := append(b,a...)
```

but how do i do this elegantly?

`c := append(a,b...) <-- what's the solution does anyone knows?`

Would like to have the c[0] == a, c[1:] == b for checking next time

Comment: You cannot append to arrays in Go. Arrays are fixed-length. But you don't have an array, you have a slice.

Comment: Beyond that, what you have is already pretty elegant. What are you hoping to improve?

Answer (score 2):

You can make `a` a slice as well then append it with `b`.

```
c := append([]byte{a}, b...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bytes.Buffer to make this cleaner:

```
var a byte
var buf bytes.Buffer

buf.WriteByte(a)// For a single byte
buf.Write([]byte{a})// For byte slice
```

Comment: Why bytes.buffer? is it slower or faster?

Comment: It is a handy wrapper around byte slice, and also it implements several interfaces, io.Reader, io.Writer to name a few. It is an ideal choice when you have a lot of values to append, and also it provides methods for efficient conversion of byte slice to string.